# How to set AWS EC2 CPU utilization to max or use all cores

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On AWS, my EC2 instance drops to 75% and sometimes to 50% cpu utilization.

I know AWS has a setting for GPU's to use max cores. Does AWS EC2 have this setting for CPU anywhere?

Comment: This question seems to portray a misunderstanding of how CPUs, cores, hyperthreads (vCPUs), and threads actually work.  Your code will always use as much of the CPU as it needs and is able to use, and there is no way to change that in an upward direction, because it is already maximum, by definition.  For example, on a machine with 4 vCPU, you must have at least 4 threads running and waiting on the CPU at all times to sustain 100% utilization.  3 running and 1 blocking on something else (say, I/O) would mean a max of ~75%.  What is your workload and why do you want high usage instead of low?

Comment: I know how CPU's and threads work.  AWS does not set all setting to max. They what do what they feel is safe. Well, I dont want safe. I want to assured that if I am paying for x cores. All x cores are available all times for my programs to use. AWS does not use all GPU Cores as a default.  So that begs the question. Does it do the same on CPUs. I have seen the Util. start at 100% (8 cores). then drop to 75%(6 cores).  and stay at 6. Until I reboot, then it back 100%.

Comment: While your usage is at 75%, where the rest of the time being spent?  It must necessarily be some combination of idle, user, system, niced, iowait, hw/sw interrupts, or stolen cycles that all adds up to 100%, so the question is... where are the cycles going?  They must be spent somewhere, and if, for example, a core's clock speed is reduced while workload remains constant, the utilization stats would rise (up to a maximum of 100%), not fall.  There's no parallel here to GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do.

The high level overview is: you can specify number of CPU cores and threads per core via API/CLI during instance launch.  Once launched, you cannot change this.

For the specific rules, Refer to this document:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html

To view the CPU settings for your instance, run:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <your instance ids here>
```

Comment: While this is useful info in other scenarios, I don't think it is what OP is looking for.  It sounds like they are under the impression that EC2 is somehow limiting the CPU they use and they want to uncap it -- which isn't a thing -- but if it were, it would be the opposite (sort of) of what you have, here.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the instance type(resizing the instance)

Refer here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resize-instance/